# Div with reCaptcha error won't show

Tags: javascript, html, css, recaptcha

I have a `reCaptcha` inside `Vue` component as a part of my register form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <vue-recaptcha sitekey="KEY"></vue-recaptcha>
    <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors.register.recaptcha" v-for="value in errors.register.recaptcha">
        <strong>{{value}}</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is when I get message in `errors.register.recaptcha` - it doesn't appear in `div` I specified for show recaptcha error. I see that `div` in `DOM` console tab, I see error's text inside `<strong></strong>`, but I don't actually see it on the page. What's wrong? reCaptcha neighbourhood might prevent showing other elements?

I have some other groups which contains `input` + `div` where error might appeared and there are no problems to show an error.

**Update**: I noticed that only this one `div` with `class="invalid-feedback"` is `display: none`. All other `div` with the same class has `display: block`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding hidden input

```
<input class="form-control"
    :class="{' is-invalid': errors.register.recaptcha}"
    hidden>
```

The whole element might be

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control"
        :class="{' is-invalid': errors.register.recaptcha}"
        hidden>
    <vue-recaptcha sitekey="KEY"></vue-recaptcha>
    <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors.register.recaptcha" v-for="value in errors.register.recaptcha">
        <strong>{{value}}</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```